# how to filter string but keep some tags

Tags: java

how can i filter string?

> `String[] filterTags={<A>,<BC>,<A,<B};`

**filterTags can contains more values it can contains some string, numeric or anything can grow dyanmically**

```
String name="<A><ABC><B><B"
```

what i want is remove values from filterTags array but keep `<ABC>` as it is from the name(String)

```
if (name.contains(filterTags[i])and ???)
```

i need just a simple check which will remove the filterTags values if contains in name (String) but keep  as it is

thank you in advanced

Comment: I'm confused - what code do you currently have that is working or what you have done so far?  What logic dictates removing the tags other than "<ABC>".  What should the final state of the String be?

Comment: i need just a simple check which will remove the filterTags values if contains from name but keep <ABC> as it is

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this with a regex:

```
String filtered = name.replaceAll("(<A>|<BC>|<A|<B)", "");
// filtered == "<ABC>"
```

The problem is now to create that regex String. You can hardcode it, since it looks like that's what you're doing with the array anyways, or you could do something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
for (String token : filterTags) {
    sb.append(token);
    sb.append('|');
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // Remove the last "|"
sb.append(')');
String regex = sb.toString();
```

Note that this will only work if your filter tags don't contain any regex special characters

Comment: Very minor, but good practice, optimization - use `sb.append('|')` and `sb.append(')')`.  If its only a character thats getting append it saves the StringBuilder quite a bit of work in determining the size of the string, unpacking it to characters and appending each character. Compare [StringBuilder.append(String)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28java.lang.String%29) to the char based append call.

Comment: Thats only the `append()` call - doesn't exist for the constructor (which still takes a String (or an int for capacity)).

Answer (score 0):

Simply you Can do this with regex

```
String name = "<A><ABC><c<B<s";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(<ABC>).*");
        matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
        matcher.matches();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // prints <ABC>
```